# How to create a none square gui in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello how does one go about creating a none square gui with tkinter (or python)

I always thought the gui of this software was beautiful and would like to recreate it.
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/wp-content/uploads/Live-Linux-USB-Creator.jpg

Is there a way i could build a gui on an image?
Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can build a "GUI" on top of an image.

Just make a canvas, use `create_image` and place it according. Then, you can use `place` / `create_window` to put further widgets on the canvas on top of this background image.

You may find it easier to use a simple label widget with a lower stacking order, and then you can grid / pack / place widgets on top of this.

You can make a background using a label by doing:

```
bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(some image path)
bg = tk.Label(parent, image=bg_image)
bg.image = bg_image #Save a reference
bg.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Although, you're not going to be able to get the transparency affects like you see in the image linked.

Comment: As @pythonista said (without actually saying it), you should be using TK, not Tkinter. Tkinter is a wrapper and not likely to support the dynamic nature you'll need to accomplish your desired effect.